# Unique series for repeating 3 numbers 27 times

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am an amateur magician and learning lots about math while advancing my magical knowledge.

One particular trick uses 3 numbers collectively repeated 27 times.

At any point in this ordering you can select 3 numbers in a row and they will be a unique combination. It runs circular meaning the end 2 numbers and the top one will also be unique.

An example is;

111222333113322131321232312

Does anyone know the name of this? I thought the lecturer named it a "Turner DeBreaux Cycle" but I can't find this reference anywhere (I may be spelling it wrong).

The name of the cycle/series. Who discovered it or where I can read more about it would be greatly appreciated. I could have blindly put together the order eventually hitting on the right combination but I am desperate to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence ... De Bruijn !!

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to a [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, thank you both. Can one of you answer below so I can accept it (I don't see how to accept a comment).

Answer (score 1):

> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence ... De Bruijn !!
>   Donald Splutterwit

Answered first by Donald Splutterwit in the comments below the question. Many thanks!